# Ampscript to change a certain value in a dynamic field

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions, formatting

So our data team is passing a value in a data extension that they want to display as a dollar sign, e.g. "$0.499". However, when read in our email, it displays the HTML and not '$'. Is there Ampscript I could utilize that says Change '$' = '$'? Or, better yet, is there a way within the email to formulate the field so that it displays in American dollar format e.g. '$.499'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your currency value in your Data Extension is a decimal type, you can use the [Format()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Format.htm) function within AMPScript to format the value as currency. In your instance, it sounds like you're looking to format as a currency with three decimal places e.g. "$.499":

```
%%=Format(my_decimal_field,"$#,#.000;-$#,#.000")=%%
```

Or if you want the number of dollars when zero to be presented e.g. "$0.499":

```
%%=Format(my_decimal_field,"C3",null,"en-US")=%%
```

Comment: Thank you Macca! This works. As you can tell still fairly new to Ampscript. Appreciate the support!

Comment: No worries, @chorlesbarkley7. Get creative. It's SFMC's secret sauce. Enjoy!