# Replacing HTML Code in a String

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, string, formatting

We're being passed a field in a data string with the HTML code '`&dollar;`'. We're wanting to change that to '$', since when we send emails it still shows as '`&dollar;`' and not '$' on a web page. We attempted to format using C3 with the following Ampscript: `%%=Format(Field_Rate, "C3", null, "en-US")=%%`. It's displaying correctly in testing within Marketing Cloud, however the email sends aren't making it to the appropriate inbox. Are we able to utilize the Replace function in Ampscript to replace '`&dollar;`' with '$'?

Comment: Can you describe the difference between the '$'? I do not seem to understand the difference. Does it has something to do with your own question? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305006/ampscript-to-change-a-certain-value-in-a-dynamic-field

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick p.s. SFSE decodes HTML entities, so that's why you may have been confused. I edited it to be less confusing.

Comment: This relates to this question on how to format a field to currency using AMPScript's Format() https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305006/ampscript-to-change-a-certain-value-in-a-dynamic-field/305022#305022. Could we understand what's the data in your Data Extension that this is working on? The response was assuming you had a Number/Decimal field you're formatting.

Comment: @Macca The data in the field passedis as follows: e.g.  '&dollar;0.499' . I thought the solution in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/305006/ampscript-to-change-a-certain-value-in-a-dynamic-field/305022#305022 would resolve, but it seems that is causing email send issues.

Comment: @chorlesbarkley7 If the formatting of your data's consistent, you could just try replacing the HTML encode dollar symbol - %%=Format(Replace(my_field,,"&dollar;",""),"$#,#.000;-$#,#.000")=%%